# program is not working "TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'"

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris=load_iris()
dir(iris)
#output data to traixn setosa,versicolor and virginica
x=iris.data
#fetching data
x=np.delete(x, np.s_[::50], 0)
#print(x)
y=iris.target
#featching output
y=np.delete(y, np.s_[::50], 0)
algo=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier
```

when i try to use fit it does not support

```
train=algo.fit(x,y)
res=train.pridict([test_setosa])
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change something in your code. The `DecisionTreeClassifier` is a class and the way your call it in your code is wrong.

**Replace**

```
algo=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier
```

**with**

```
algo=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

---

### Full code

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np

iris=load_iris()
dir(iris)
#output data to traixn setosa,versicolor and virginica
x=iris.data
#fetching data
x=np.delete(x, np.s_[::50], 0)
#print(x)
y=iris.target
#featching output
y=np.delete(y, np.s_[::50], 0)

algo=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

train=algo.fit(x,y)
res=train.predict([test_setosa])
```

Comment: thank you.. that was the only thing that was missing in my code